# How do you save a Firebase snapshot to a variable to be used elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, firebase-authentication

Is it even possible?

I've seen this question come up quite a lot on here, but it doesn't seem that anyone is given quite the answer I'm looking for. Suppose you have the following, code that is supposed to get a Firebase object from your database and return the value:

```
function get(target){
    return database.ref(target).once("value",function(snapshot){
        //console.log(snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

In my case, the expectation is to return an object, namely `{"hello":"world"}`. However, my result is always `Promise {<pending>}`. I've tinkered with this a bit and the only other outputs I've been about to get are, `undefined` and `Promise {<resolved> {"hello":"world"}}`. The latter was almost what I wanted, but still not quite.

How can I set up the function `get()` such that it returns the actual value of `snapshot.val()` and not the promise. For example:

```
let response = get("/foo");
console.log(response["hello"]);
```

The result of this should be `world`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `Promise` to be able to use the obje t elsewhere:

```
function get(target){
    return Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
database.ref(target).once("value",function(snapshot){
        //console.log(snapshot.val());
        resolve(snapshot.val());
     });
    });
}
```

Then when you call this function, you can do the following :

```
get(target).then((data) =>{
  console.log(data);
});
```